# Can I restrict an SQL account from system tables / functions?

Tags: sql-server

I've got a piece of vendor software that comes with a MS-SQL database. The software has a user account configured to access the MS-SQL database. Is it possible to restrict that account from accessing things beyond vendor tables/functions?

For example. I don't want this user to be able to call anything like @@SomeFunction or some_function() if it is something that is native to SQL Server. I also don't want it to be able to call into things like syslogins / sysobjects /syscolumns, etc.

So something like this: `SELECT *,db_user() FROM sysobjects` - Not allowed

Something like this: `SELECT *,vendorfunction(column) FROM VendorTable1 INNER JOIN VendorTable2 ...` Allowed

Is there a way to blanket deny native SQL functions/tables/Stored Procedure to a user?

Comment: Are you familiar with the [DENY](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188338.aspx) statement?